# Pytube throws AgeRestrictedError on some non-age-restricted videos

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

pytube throws *pytube.exceptions.AgeRestrictedError* on some videos that are not age restricted. Some videos can be downloaded, but some can not. I did not find a difference between the videos yet.

- bypass_age_gate() does not help
- logging in does not help

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube("https://youtu.be/vUzGV4F7He8")
if yt.age_restricted == False:
    yt.streams.filter(adaptive=True, file_extension="mp4").first().download()
```

→ pytube.exceptions.AgeRestrictedError

I did not find a working solution. Is there any?

After a lot of investigation I found a way:
I edited the function bypass_age_gate and set the client to "WEB". But now I am getting:

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.

Answer (score -4):

The issue you are experiencing with pytube is a known bug that has been reported on GitHub. The bug is caused by a change in the way that YouTube generates signatures for age-restricted videos.

There is no known workaround for this bug at this time. However, the developers of pytube are working on a fix, and it is expected to be released in a future version of the library.

In the meantime, there are a few workarounds that you can try:

- Use a different YouTube video downloader. There are a number of other
  YouTube video downloaders available, both online and offline. Some of
  these downloaders may be able to download age-restricted videos that
  pytube cannot.
- Use a proxy server. A proxy server can be used to hide
  your IP address from YouTube. This may allow you to download
  age-restricted videos without having to log in.
- Use a YouTube Premium
  account. YouTube Premium subscribers can download any video on
  YouTube, regardless of whether it is age-restricted or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy